# Articles and Papers about the math behind Rubik's Cube

Tags: group-theory, rubiks-cube

I'm very interested in the math behind the Rubik's Cube. I already found this:
https://people.kth.se/~boij/kandexjobbVT11/Material/rubikscube.pdf

Are there some  others texts that deal with the Rubik's Cube like a "Math thing"?

Comment: You might try [this](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~jjchen/docs/Group%20Theory%20and%20the%20Rubik%27s%20Cube.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

My go-to reference for the Rubik's Cube Group is [Adventures in Group Theory: Rubik's Cube, Merlin's Machine, and Other Mathematical Toys](http://a.co/cMXcFfh) by David Joyner

Answer (score 1):

David Singmaster published some of the earliest mathematical analysis of Rubik's cube in the early 1980s - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Singmaster for links.